# Include python-dropbox in Yocto

Tags: python, linux, dropbox, yocto, recipe

My Python application uses Dropbox and I need to include this library in my Yocto image. I managed to generate a recipe for it with pipoe (`pipoe -p dropbox`). Here it is:

```
SUMMARY = "Official Dropbox API Client"
HOMEPAGE = "http://www.dropbox.com/developers"
AUTHOR = "Dropbox <dev-platform@dropbox.com>"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=ef3219362ea5e452a18031af12f35eb6"

SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/33/bffd4a7596f3280f8bd2796b4f09c5c701b99d5c8e68715351cc2b3eeca8/dropbox-10.3.0.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "f6d1a30af7e202237d660213d22e48a7"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "5f296f13ee7c358ab41779a73c4922ed81199447566c1a4c8fbf23dbcda25e20"

S = "${WORKDIR}/dropbox-10.3.0"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "python-requests python-six "

inherit setuptools
```

When I run it, it says:

```
| ERROR: Do not try to fetch `pytest-runner' for building. Please add its native recipe to DEPENDS.
```

and then

```
| raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
| pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pytest-runner' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

so I added the following line to the generated recipe:

```
DEPENDS = "python3-pytest-runner-native "
```

But I still get the same error. Any idea?

Comment: Probably an issue with inconsistent Python version.
You inherit setuptools which is for python2. The RDEPENDS are for python2 dependencies. But you add python3-pytest-runner-native in DEPENDS.
I'd suggest to find out which python version to use for this software and use the same for all RDEPENDS, inherited classes (setuptools3 for python3), and DEPENDS. If the issue still persists, there's probably something else to do :)

Comment: Yep, that was it! Once I changed python3 to python in my DEPENDS bitbake ended successfully, thanks. If you write it as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably an issue with inconsistent Python version.

You `inherit setuptools` which is for python2. The `RDEPENDS` are for python2 dependencies. But you add `python3-pytest-runner-native` in `DEPENDS`.

I'd suggest finding out which python version to use for this software and use the same for all `RDEPENDS`, inherited classes (`setuptools3` for python3), and `DEPENDS`.